# Declare two classes from eachother

Tags: java, class

I'm writing a app in NetBeans. I have two classes MyApp_View and MyApp_Functions.

The MyApp_View class starts like this

```
public class MyApp_View extends FrameView {
MyApp_Functions My_functions = new MyApp_Functions();

public MyApp_View(SingleFrameApplication app) {
    super(app);
```

In MyApp_Functions I have
`MyApp_View my_view = new MyApp_View(null);`

I want to access the public variables in MyApp_View from MyApp_Functions and the public methods in functions from view, but have no success with this.

Is this doable? And how?

Edit:
Judging by the answer I got I think it's best to clarify.

If I declare MyApp_View in MyApp_Functions *or* MyApp_Functions in MyApp_View, it works as expected. But I can't access public stuff in both classes from the other. I can obviously only access things from the one I declared.

If I try to declare MyApp_View in MyApp_Functions and MyApp_Functions in MyApp_View they compile fine. But I get a null exception error on start.

Again. Easier to understand? Is this doable? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MyApp_View my_view = new MyApp_View(null);

This creates a new `MyApp_View` object, which is not the same as the one that constructed the `MyApp_Function`.  It sounds like what you want is to have the two objects have references to each other.  I usually set that up using a parameter in the constructor for one of the objects.  Here's an example:

```
class A {
    private B b;

    public A() {
        this.b = new B(this);
    }
}

class B {
    private A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Now objects of type `A` can access the associated object `B` through `A.b`, and the object `B` can access the associated object `A` through `B.a`.  In your example, `A` is `MyApp_View`, and `B` is `MyApp_Functions`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a reference from one to the other. At its most basic it would invlove changing your second line to:

```
MyApp_Functions My_functions = new MyApp_Functions(this);
```

and adding the appropriate constructor to MyApp_functions that 'saves' the reference in a variable, which can then be used whenever you need to access something from MyApp_View.

Ultimately though, you want to ask if such relationships are really necessary and perhaps re-architect the system to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the public members is easy -- for example, just using `My_functions.foo` will access the public `foo` variable on your object `My_functions` of the `MyApp_Functions` class, and likewise using `my_view.bar()` will call the public `bar()` method on that object.

I suspect, though, that your problem is a more general one with object-oriented thinking; I recommend picking up an introductory Java book and working through it -- there's really no substitute for a good solid grounding in the way OO programmers *think*.

Comment: Personal recommendation: "Head First Java" by Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates

Comment: for OO, I would rather suggest some SmallTalk or Ruby book:))